# Coefficients of derivatives of $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2j+1}}{\mathrm{d} x^{2j+1}}\left(f(x) \mathrm{e}^{g(x)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I am trying to calculate the derivative

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2j+1}}{\mathrm{d} x^{2j+1}}\left(f(x) \mathrm{e}^{g(x)}\right).
$$

The problem I am looking at doesn't require me to calculate the entire derivative. Instead I am looking at specific components of the derivative having the form

$$
\frac{\partial^{2j+1}}{\partial x^{2j+1}}\left(f(x) \mathrm{e}^{g(x)}\right) = \mathrm{e}^{g(x)} 
\big[c_1(j)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(g(x))\right)^{2j+1}f(x) \, + c_2(j)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(g(x))\right)^{2j}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(f(x))\right) \\ + c_3(j)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(g(x))\right)^{2j-1}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}(f(x))\right) + c_4(j)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(g(x))\right)^{2j-2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}x^3}(f(x))\right) \\ + \cdots + c_{2j}(j)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(g(x))\right)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2j}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2j}}(f(x))\right) + c_{2j+1}(j)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2j+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2j+1}}(f(x))\right)\big] \\
+ \text{lots of unimportant derivatives}  .
$$

The difficulty I am having is determining the coefficients $c_1(j)$, $c_2(j)$, $\cdots$, $c_{2j}(j)$, $c_{2j+1}(j)$.

The problem contains some symmetry such that $c_1(j)=c_{2j+1}(j)$, $c_2(j) = c_{2j}(j)$, and $c_n(j) = c_{2j+2-n}(j)$.

So far I have determined

$$
c_1 = 1
$$

$$
c_2 = j(2j+1)
$$

$$
c_3 = j(4j^2-1)/3
$$

$$
c_4 = \binom{5j}{j}/(4j+1)
$$

I am guessing this has already be solved somewhere and I think there should be some application of binomials that gives the coefficients, however, my combinatorics is not up to scratch.

Is anyone able to give me a direct formula for all of the coefficients $c_j$?

Comment: Probably not so efficient but you may try combining the general Leibniz rule and Faà di Bruno's formula. Or you may write down a recursion.

Comment: Thanks gary, it ends up just being the binomial coefficients of the general Leibniz rule.

Comment: Have you lost an $\exp(g(x))$ on each term of the RHS?

Comment: Oh yeah there is also supposed to be an extra exp(g(x)) for all of them as well. The coefficients are still the same regardless. I have also found the $c_4$ as written is incorrect. I have since moved on to a new part of my problem. This involves calculating the coefficients for terms with a 

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} g(x)$$ 

Fortunately the asymptotics of my problems means that these will be the only terms that occur in the first and second orders of my problem and I can stop there.

The suggestion of Leibniz rule and Faà di Bruno's formula from @Gary helped